# Backspace doesn't work in gvim 7.2 64-bit for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, vim, windows-7-x64, backspace

I just installed the [64-bit zipped version for Windows of gvim](http://vim-win3264.googlecode.com/files/vim72.zip) on my new machine at work, and [I changed some settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395947/how-to-get-gvim-to-play-nicely-with-visual-studio-2010) to make it compatible with Visual Studio 2010.

Now the backspace key doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my .vimrc file:

```
set nowrap
set ruler
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set ff=dos
```

It's only a minor annoyance (the delete key works), but I was just wondering if anybody knew.

Comment: Wild guess, have you earlier had source mswin.vim in your vimrc and now it's missing?

Comment: @Johnny I do have that file (mswin.vim) in my C:\Program Files\vim72

Comment: I'm no vim expert but I have noticed that backspace works in a different way if `source mswin.vim` is missing from the vimrc file. Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V also will not copy/paste

Comment: If you need to check it, I found this link helps: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Does it entirely not work, or does it just not backspace past where you went into insert mode? There's an option [`backspace`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backspace%27) which controls this:

```
Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W and CTRL-U in Insert
mode.  This is a list of items, separated by commas.  Each item allows
a way to backspace over something:
value       effect
indent      allow backspacing over autoindent
eol         allow backspacing over line breaks (join lines)
start       allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U
            stop once at the start of insert.
```

[owen_water's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419848/backspace-doesnt-work-in-gvim-7-2-64-bit-for-windows/5427461#5427461) is the same as Carpetsmoker's comment, enabling all three of these. That's generally what people want, since it's a bit surprising to have Vim refuse to let you backspace text that's right there. So take your pick of the two equivalent choices - I'd go with the more verbose and clear one:

```
set backspace=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

In some cases, bad terminals can mess with backspace and delete, but I doubt that's your problem in Windows. There is some ability to fix this; see [`:help fixdel`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:fixdel).

Comment: In Cygwin on Windows7, I used the following .vimrc to fix the backspace issue. `set nocompatible
syntax on
set nu
set ts=2
set autoindent
set bs=2
set bs=indent,eol,start
fixdel`

Comment: @Jerry: `nocompatible` is set (rather, `compatible` is off) by default if you have a vimrc, syntax highlighting, line numbering, tabstops, and indentation are irrelevant, so your solution is exactly what I posted, plus some redundancy - `backspace=2` and `backspace=indent,eol,start` are completely equivalent.

Comment: You are right, @Jefromi I just copy my whole .vimrc to confirm that your answer also works in Cygwin too. Should only focus on the relevant part to make the answer clear.

Comment: Using Windows 8.1 with the grapic version of Vim 7.4 the `set backspace=indent,eol,start` command allowed me to use backspace just like I do in Linux, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

never use vim in Windows, but I have meet the same problem before in open solaris.
Just try:

```
set backspace=2
```

Comment: I have: `set backspace=indent,eol,start` in my `~/.vimrc`